# "Amply funded, and consisting of many high born, wealthy gentlemen..."

Tags: sentence

Could you explain what the sentence bolded means in the following passage ?

> In the minds of the Royal Society's founders, the society was meant to
>   serve a double purpose. **Amply funded, and consisting of many high
>   born, wealthy gentlemen, the society served to check the tendency to
>   sacrifice the thorough search for truth to the prospect of immediate
>   profit, and thus prod the Fellows to see their discoveries from
>   conception to application in a continuous process, rather than
>   exposing new theories as soon as they cropped up, without thinking
>   them out fully.** The second purpose of the society was to...

---

extra information

> One of the most prominent features of the Royal Society was that it
>   admitted as Fellows men of all religions, professions, origins, and
>   classes. It sought to promote a universal culture of peace throughout
>   Europe, and shunned war and discrimination.

http://www.sparknotes.com/history/european/scientificrevolution/section9.rhtml

Comment: That is a long and intricate sentence, but its meaning seems clearly built up from its component parts. What is it that you are having trouble with?

Comment: @ColinFine Fine The paaraghrap start firstly by telling about  "Amply funded, and consisting of many high born, wealthy gentlemen"   and then it says " the society served to check the tendency to sacrifice the thorough" which does not quite make a sense for me,  and then it says  "as soon as they cropped up, without thinking them out fully" ..these are the parts I cant translate.

Comment: @ColinFine   I got the part  "and thus prod the Fellows to see their discoveries from conception to application in a continuous process, rather than exposing new theories "  .I assume that " to prod" means to encourage and I am not sure what " to crop up " means.. The thing is for the first time these parts seems unrelated to each other .

Comment: @ColinFine Why  is mentioned about gentlemens and then said "the society served.." who is society, what does " society serves" mean?  what does " to check the tendency to sacrifice" means?

Comment: "Crop up" you can find in any good dictionary: it means "occur unexpectedly". The Society is The Royal Society (the subject of the paragraph), whose members originally were mostly gentlemen. "Serves to" is an elegant phrase for "does". One of the meanings of "check" is "halt", or "limit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Amply funded, and consisting of many high born, wealthy gentlemen, the
>   society served to check the tendency to sacrifice the thorough search
>   for truth to the prospect of immediate profit, and thus prod the
>   Fellows to see their discoveries from conception to application in a
>   continuous process, rather than exposing new theories as soon as they
>   cropped up, without thinking them out fully.

It is quite a mouthful!

**Paraphrase**

The society was well funded and consisted of many high born, wealthy gentlemen. Its purpose was to discourage the tendency of its fellows to publish their theories before they had thought them through and investigated them properly.  Before this, they would neglect proper research in favour of immediate profit.